# Statement complementarily reverse to given

Tags: phrase-requests

Person A stated some noble motives behind actions person B found suspicious.

> [Person B] answered with very measured words, her smile not quite reaching to her eyes. "If what you claim is true, then you can count me as your friend." The unsaid **counterpart** of the sentence hung heavily in the air.

I'm not quite sure if *counterpart* conveys the meaning well. Is there a better phrase to fit that meaning? How would you call the sentence: *"If what you claim is a lie, then you can count me as your enemy*." in relation to the one given in the quote?

Comment: The [contrapositive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) is always equivalent to the original: [P → Q, ¬Q ⊢ ¬P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens).  “If you count me no friend, then what you claim is false.” So *counterpart* doesn’t seem too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer the formulation "...the unsaid **corollary**..." (I might even use "unstated" rather than "unsaid").

m-w.com gives this as one definition of corollary: "something that incidentally or naturally accompanies or parallels."  In this case, the unstated *"If what you claim is a lie, then you can count me as your enemy"* "naturally accompanies" the vocalized part of the statement.